# Can't get bar chart to grid properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried a number of things but I can't get my plot to create a grid. What I want is a stacked filled chart but I keep getting errors I can't figure out. If my data only has year (Cycle) this works.

```
p2000 <- ggplot(c2000,aes(x=c2000$RealCode, y=c2000$Amount, fill=c2000$Party,     colors=c2000$Party)) +
    geom_bar(position="fill",colour="black") + cbgFillPalette + xlab("") + ylab("") +     opts(title="2000")+
    opts(legend.position = "none")+geom_hline(yintercept = .5, colour = "black")+
    facet_grid(. ~ Cycle)
p2000
```

But if I have more than one year, I get y not found error.

```
c2000[1:5,]
  RealCode Cycle Party  Amount
1        A  2000     D 5581676
2        B  2000     D 2547396
3        C  2000     D 6867211
4        D  2000     D 2839314
5        E  2000     D 6255726
> p2000 <- ggplot(c2000,aes(x=c2000$RealCode, y=c2000$Amount, fill=c2000$Party,         colors=c2000$Party)) +
+     geom_bar(position="fill",colour="black") + cbgFillPalette + xlab("") + ylab("") +     opts(title="2000")+
+     opts(legend.position = "none")+geom_hline(yintercept = .5, colour = "black")+
+     facet_grid(. ~ Cycle)
> p2000
Error in pmin(y, 0) : object 'y' not found
> p2000 <- ggplot(c2000,aes(x=c2000$RealCode, y=c2000$Amount, fill=c2000$Party,     colors=c2000$Party)) +
+     geom_bar(position="fill",colour="black") + cbgFillPalette + xlab("") + ylab("") +     opts(title="2000")+
+     opts(legend.position = "none")+geom_hline(yintercept = .5, colour = "black")+
+     facet_grid(. ~ c2000$Cycle)
> p2000
Error in layout_base(data, cols, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

This is what one plot looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGdvV.jpg

Comment: I can't help much without a reproducible example, but at the very least you definitely shouldn't be mapping aesthetics like `x = c2000$RealCode`. You should just be doing `x = RealCode`.

Comment: Changing everything to just be the Column names fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my comment appeared to be the correct answer, I'll add it as an answer.

You shouldn't be mapping aesthetics using `x = c2000$RealCode`. Rather, you specify your data frame at the start of the `ggplot` call, and then the aesthetic mappings should simply specify the name of columns in that data frame. So you probably want to convert them all to things like `x = RealCode`.

Otherwise `ggplot` will get confused about where to look for things when building the plot.